# How can i collect all the data from the name value so i can use it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  let inpPas = document.querySelector('#inpPas');
  let btnGo = document.querySelector('#btnGo');


  const db = firebase.database();
  let ref = db.ref('xVerdi');


  let rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('xVerdi');
  rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {

    let name = snap.child('name').val();

    btnGo.onclick = goPassword;

    function goPassword(){

        if (inpPas.value == name) {
          alert("yeyeye")
        }

      console.log("her " + name)
    }

    console.log(name)
  })
```

I want to use all the data that i have stored in this name: value, but i can only use the most resent one. Any suggestions?

Comment: add the values to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
let nameList = [];
let rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('xVerdi');
  rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
let name = snap.child('name').val();
nameList.push(name);
```